How do I reduce the multiple thread instances to single thread instance in the ASP.NET Core Web API?
I am running the GRPC ASP.NET Core Web API. I want to reduce the multiple thread instance to single thread instance. So I used pstree command to see how many threads it invoked.
This is the output:
  ├─node─┬─bash───dotnet─┬─TestGRPC───25*[{TestGRPC}]
    │           │      │               └─16*[{dotnet}]
    │           │      ├─2*[bash───htop]
    │           │      ├─bash───pstree
    │           │      └─14*[{node}]

We can see that it is invoking 25 thread instance. I tried to reduce it to 4 thread instances using below code. But it didn't work.
bool isMin = ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(1, 1);
bool isMax = ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(4, 4);

builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
{
    serverOptions.Limits.MaxConcurrentConnections = 1;
});

Here is the output I got after setting the max threads to 4 and min threads to 1
 ├─node───12*[{node}]
    │           ├─node─┬─bash───dotnet─┬─TestGRPC───26*[{TestGRPC}]
    │           │      │               └─23*[{dotnet}]
    │           │      ├─2*[bash───htop]
    │           │      ├─bash───pstree
    │           │      └─14*[{node}]

Could someone please help me to control the number of thread instances invoked by ASP.NET Core Web API?

What is the actual goal? Why do you want to reduce the number of threads? I think the framework creates a few threads for internal use, so I'm not sure your idea is possible.

@JonasH, I am doing an experiment to determine if reducing the number of thread instances leads to an increase in queries per second (QPS).

Then measure QPS with different server settings. Unused threads has only a minor impact on memory use, so just counting the total number of threads is not a very meaningful metric. And configuring the thread pool is probably not the best way to optimize throughput, it could easily result in problems if the application blocks a threadpool thread for whatever reason. Configuring the various limits on the server seem like the better option, that is what they are there for.

controlled by app pool... maybe check here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/runtime-config/threading
